# Client Side Pagination : $(......).dataTable() is not a function

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

I am currently working on client side pagination and i got stuck in it.so i am looking for a help
Below is my code in jsp:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

and my table is :

```
<table id="logTable" class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Transaction Log
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Updated On
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Updated By
                    </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <c:if test="${fn:length(transactionLogList) gt 0}">
                    <c:forEach var="tLog" items="${transactionLogList}">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                ${tLog.remarks}
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                ${tLog.created }
                            </th>
                            <th>${tLog.username}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
             </tbody>
            </table>
```

And my jquery datatable function is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logTable').dataTable();
      });
```

And i got following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> 
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

How to get rid from this error

Comment: Where did you include your DataTable codes? Did you wrap it in `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: It should be `dataTable();` instead of `.DataTable` ? For eg: `$('#logTable').dataTable();`

Comment: i just included datatable code

Comment: Looks like script loading issue!Check for couple of points 1)jQuery js is loaded on page only once 2)jquery is loaded before dataTables js 3)Both the versions for jQuery and dataTables are compatible! For you jQuery version 1.11.2 while for dataTables 1.10.13,check for compatibility too